# Control Audio with main view controller from UITableViewController using @protocol?

Tags: protocols, uitableview, avaudioplayer, popover

Ok here's the scenario:

I am using AVAudioPlayer.

I am trying to select and play a song from UITableView which appears as a popover.

The mp3 assets are located in my documents directory.

I can populate the table view and when I select a row, play that specific asset.

What I can not do is control the audio once the popover has disappeared with the controls that are on my main view controller. (play/stop/volume)

I have @protocol which makes the popover a delegate, can any one help me with the syntax of the method that would go in my protocol?

@protocol SongChooserDelegate

-(void) didTap:(NSData *) data;  <------------ I'm guessing here

@end

If this won't work - what will?

Thank you, any help would be greatly appreciated.... this is my last step in building my app for my senior thesis due Friday!!!!! eeeek.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while, but I figured this out finally:
If any one wants and explanation or all the code, let me know.

//UITableViewController.h

@protocol SongChooserDelegate

-(void) didTap:(NSURL *)songUrl;

@end

//UITableView.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
  [self.player prepareToPlay];

  // Point to Document directory
  NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() 
                    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
  NSError *error = nil;
  NSArray *array = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                    contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&error];
  if (array == nil) {
      // Handle the error
  }
  self.songs = array;

  [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  UIAlertView *showSelection;
  NSString *message;
  message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",
             [songs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
  showSelection = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                   initWithTitle:@"Track Selected" message:message delegate:nil
                   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [showSelection show];
  [showSelection release];
  [message release];

  NSString *applicationDocumentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
  NSString *filePath = [applicationDocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: [songs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
  NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

  [self.delegate didTap:url];

  }

//ViewController.h

@interface ViewController : UIViewController < SongChooserDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate >

//ViewController.m

-(void) didTap:(NSURL *)songUrl{

```
 player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:songUrl error:nil];
```

[player prepareToPlay];

}